# Do I lose my temporary tables when changing tasks in an SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm writing an SSIS package that imports data from an Oracle database. There's a chance some rows are already in the destination table, and seeing that there's no task in SSIS 2008 that allows me to check this, my idea is to create a temporary table and use a field in the destination table to filter the temporary table's rows that I can actually insert.

I understand that local and global temporary tables [vanish when they go out of scope](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/). So, my question is, when my SSIS package goes on to the next task, will my temporary tables disappear?

Comment: The lookup task lets you check if rows already exist. But I think the database method is a better way of doing it. I can't tell you if a temporary table disappears for the next task but I suggest you use a permanent table not a temporary table if you have that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your connection manager(s), you need to set RetainSameConnection = True. This ensures that your connection doesn't close throughout the execution of the package - using the same spid.

You'll also need to set DelayValidation = True for many of your tasks (without seeing your package, I can't tell you all of them, but you can experiment). By default, SSIS tries to pre-validate all the steps in your package before executing. When you're using temp tables, if the temp table doesn't exist, this pre-validation will fail. By setting DelayValidation = True, you avoid the pre-validation.

Finally, you may need to do some weird stuff to get the package to recognize your temp table at design time - e.g. Execute the task that creates your temp table, then try to map your fields (assuming you're going to follow good practice and drop the temp table at the end of your package).

This article provides a good overview: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2826/how-to-create-and-use-temp-tables-in-ssis/

You should be able to accomplish this with either global or local temp tables.

Comment: Can't get clearer than this, thank you. I actually ended up following Robert's suggestion but I think this is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is 2 oledb sources in the package. One for the oracle table and one for the destination table. Then you do a sort on each and add a merge join on the keys of the 2 sources. In the merge join, you do a left outer join, then add a conditional split. The conditional split will have "Existing" and "New"

Existing condition will be !IsNull(DestTableID). New condition will be IsNull(DestTableID).

From the conditional split, you have an oledb sql command, which will update the destingation table if condition is Existing.

From the conditional split, you have an oledb destination, which will be the destination table and will add new rows to it if the condition is New.

Comment: I actually ended up doing this and it worked perfectly. Thanks.